# Adding UISearchBar as tableHeaderView in xib not works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I added `UISearchBar` as tableHeaderView for `UITableView` in xib, by just dropping `UISearchBar` onto `UITableView`. 
It is working fine, when the table has more than 6 rows. 
But when there is less than **6** rows, it `UITableView` does not scroll.

At the same time, if i add the `UISearchBar` as tableHeaderView for UITableView programatically in .m file using the following statement, EVERYTHING WORKS FINE.

```
tableViewTemp.tableHeaderView = searchBarFriends;
```

Seems very strange to me, 
What might be the problem?

Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little trick I did ;)  Don't make your SearchBar a subview of your UITableView.  Just add instances of them both in your nib file and wire them up as IBOutlets in your UITableViewController.  Then what you are going to do is set the SearchBar as the header view for your table, that way you don't have to worry about the frames overlapping and interfering with touch events.  Here's how you do it:

**Create the property in your TableView header file**

```
@property ( nonatomic, retain ) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

**Set the header view for your table:**

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.searchBar;  // The property you wired up in IB
}
```

**Set the height for your header or (UISearchBar)**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 44; // The height of the search bar
}
```

That's all you need.  Now this may not be the best solution if you have a grouped tableview or a table with multiple sections but its a clean solution for a simple table.  Otherwise, you'd have to adjust the frame of the searchbar AND the tableview in code because they overlap and thats why you have touch issues.  Hope this helps!

Comment: I've used this in my apps, should work like a charm.  Mark this as accepted if it does ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you add search bar like below hierarchy it will work

[image]

Comment: I added like this only buddy, but it was making UITableView not scrollable when there is less than 6 records.

Comment: Ok, Thank you Narayana, So it might be some other issue. I will check my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem (for me it wouldn't scroll at all with any number of rows, but it would as soon as I removed the search bar). Fixed it adding this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you pt2ph8, i will try this out also.